# Setar valor dentro de uma variavel Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-charts

Estou tomando uma surra daquelas para conseguir fazer alguma coisa simples(dentro do meu conhecimento de Java).

Estou carregando um *chart* do google em minha página. Em um determinado ponto, desejo obter os valores de um REST que criei e para isso, criei uma função dentro do .

O problema, e que eu não estou conseguindo pegar o valor *data* que é gerado no retorno no *$.ajax*.

```
<script>

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});

function obtemvalores(){
    var $resultado = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/messeger/webapi/myresource',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $resultado = data;             
            },
        error: function(){
            alert('Ops! Deu zebra em alguma coisa!')
            }
    });

    return $resultado;  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
       //... resto do código que gera o mapa.
```

Dentro da função obtemvalores(), observe, que eu criei uma variável chamada `$resultado`. Eu não estou conseguindo associar o valor que vem no *data* para ela, dentro do *success* do `$.ajax`.

Se eu dou um print do valor, como escrito no código, através do *console.log(data)*, dentro do *success*, o mesmo é apresentado correto. Mas passar o valor para o var que eu desejo não está indo.

Alguém poderia me da uma dica?

obs.: desejo esse valor para que ele seja retornado, como descrito na linha `return $resultado`.

--------------------------------- Tentativa 1 ----------------------------------

Complementando a pergunta, o Marcus explicou bem. Consegui fazer alguma coisa em cima do ele disse. Acredito que seja diferente o conceito de variável global do jQuery e diferente do Java(JVM), e isso pode estar me matando.

Consegui fazer o seguinte:

```
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
function obtemvalores(callbackSucesso) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/messeger/webapi/myresource',
        success: function(data) {
            callbackSucesso(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ops! Deu zebra em alguma coisa!')
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    obtemvalores(function ($resultado){
        console.log('suceso1', $resultado) <----------
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();      
            var options = {hAxis: { title: 'Time' }, vAxis: { title: 'Popularity'}}
            data.addColumn('number', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
            console.log('suceso2', $resultado);<----------
            data.addRows($resultado);
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));   
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Consigo fazer com que o meu primeiro console.log seja impresso com o valor. Agora segundo não vai mais. O que agrava, e que o serviço do google charts não inicia mais ou seja, não apresenta mais nada na tela.

Teria alguma outra ideia para setar alguma variável em um processo assíncrono e retorna o valor?

----------------------------------- Solução ------------------------------------

Consegui realizar o que eu desejava através de variável global. Segue a solução.

O que eu estava me embolando é que o googlecharts necessita de um valor em json, e eu estava passando como string ai, mesmo a montragem estando certo, ele ficava apresentando a mensagem de que não há valores. :)

Obrigado a todos

```
var enddate = "default";

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(load_page_data);

function load_page_data(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/messeger/webapi/myresource',function(data){
        chart_data = data;
        drawChart(chart_data);
        console.log(chart_data)
    });
}

function drawChart(chart_data) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows(chart_data);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o retorno da chamada AJAX é assíncrono, ou seja, quando o retorno da função `obtemvalores` ocorre, a variável `$resultado` ainda não recebeu o valor do resultado do callback de sucesso porque o servidor ainda não retornou.

Você pode resolver criando uma função com o código onde vai usar a variável `$resultado` e passá-la como callback da função `obtemResultado`, que por sua vez irá chamá-la no sucesso do `ajax` do jQuery. Mais ou menos assim:

```
function funcaoQueChamaObtemValores() {
    obtemvalores(function ($resultado) {
        // código que usa $resultado
    });
}

function obtemvalores(callbackSucesso) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/messeger/webapi/myresource',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            callbackSucesso(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ops! Deu zebra em alguma coisa!')
        }
    });
}
```

Edição:
Se quer utilizar uma variável global, terá que declarar a variável `$resultado` fora do escopo de qualquer função, mas ainda assim só poderá usa-lá quando tiver certeza que tiver sido preenchida. Então continue com o esquema de *callbacks*.

```
 var $resultado; // global

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
function obtemvalores(callbackSucesso) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/messeger/webapi/myresource',
        success: function(data) {
            $resultado = data; // <--- define o resultado, então chama o callback
            callbackSucesso();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Ops! Deu zebra em alguma coisa!')
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    obtemvalores(function () {
        console.log('suceso1', $resultado) // <----------
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();      
            var options = {hAxis: { title: 'Time' }, vAxis: { title: 'Popularity'}}
            data.addColumn('number', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
            console.log('suceso2', $resultado); // <----------
            data.addRows($resultado);
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));   
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    });//
```

Comment: Tentei aplicar o teu método, mas acredito que esteja me confundindo em alguma coisa. Complementei a minha pergunta colocando o meu teste no corpo da pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com uma solução usando a variável global. A minha solução inicial era sem o uso de global, você deveria passar por parâmetro a variável em cada método que desejasse usá-la. Ou simplesmente tente minha segunda solução.